# Change menu ul style while arriving to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styles

the code I'm searching for is very simple, simply I have divs and menu and I want that when I arrive to the first div by scrolling, the first ul in menu change its style automatically, then when I scroll to the second div the second url style change to another style, and like that... I got the answer for my question and I have the code but I don't like it because it's very tall and it contain codes for every div I got.
As I know I can find ONE short code that does the job for the WHOLE divs in jQuery.
What I want is exactly as in this code(I'm not able to let it work through http://jsfiddle.net/ if anybody knows how to load jquery there please load it and give me the url)

```
<html>
<style>
#menu {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.menutext {
    padding:25 40 30 !important;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menutext2 {
    padding:25 40 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
    color:red;
}

.alldivs {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:a9a9a9;
}
</style>
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menutext" linkId="DIV1">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV1</div>
    <div class="menutext"  linkId="DIV2">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV2</div>
    <div class="menutext"  linkId="DIV3">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV3</div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="alldivs"><div class="contentDiv" id="DIV1">DIV1</div></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div class="contentDiv" id="DIV2">DIV2</div></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div class="contentDiv" id="DIV3">DIV3</div></div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

    var menu=$('#menu'),
        menuText=menu.find('.menuText'),
        DIV1=$('#DIV1'),
        DIV2=$('#DIV2'),
        DIV3=$('#DIV3'),
        DIV1Top=DIV1.offset().top,
        DIV2Top=DIV2.offset().top,
        DIV3Top=DIV3.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var win=$(this),
        scrollTop=$(this).scrollTop();


    //to make nav menu selected according to scroll
    var start=scrollTop;
    menuText.filter('.menutext2').removeClass('menutext2').addClass('menutext');
    if(start>DIV3Top){
        menuText.filter('[linkId="DIV3"]').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
        }
    else if (start>DIV2Top){
        menuText.filter('[linkId="DIV2"]').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
        }
    else if(start>DIV1Top){
        menuText.filter('[linkId="DIV1"]').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
        }   
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: _"if anybody knows how to load jquery [in jsfiddle] please load it and give me the url"_ - Just look in the "Frameworks & Extensions" panel on the left of the jsfiddle page...

Comment: I tried to change settings there(to jQuery reader) but it doesn't work :(

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ijiwom/1/

Comment: Look again - it's the _first_ dropdown... Besides the fiddle issue, I don't understand what your question is about. You seem to be saying you want to convert some JavaScript to jQuery, but (a) jQuery _is_ JavaScript, not a separate language, and (b) the code you show already uses plenty of jQuery. Please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: _it's very tall and it's in Javascript._ your code is already in jQuery...

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @drinchev for your first comment, if you try to run the code it doesn't do the same as if you type it in notepad and try to run it on your computer

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: @AhmadTantori just click "edit" button top right

Comment: Ye I edited it, hope you can help me now :)

Comment: how hard is it to read jsfiddle docs to figure out how to load external libraries?

Comment: @charlietfl I tried hardly to load it with jsfiddle but unfortunately my jquery code doesn't work there(it doesn't take any functional action)

Comment: well if you place it in a fiddle and provide a link...others will be able to try it also without having to spend the time to copy all your code

Comment: @AhmadTantori  you miss the whole point of placing the code in a test environment to make it easier for people to help you....   and now you are insulting those people that are trying to help. Don't be ignorant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
$(function(){

  var offsets = [],
      menuText = $('#menu .menuText');

  $("div.contentDiv").each( function(i, div) {
      offsets.push({ id: div.id, offset: $(div).offset().top });
  });

  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var start = $(this).scrollTop();
    for ( var div = 0; div < offsets.length; div++ ) {
      if ( start > offsets[div].offset ) { 
        menuText.removeClass('menutext2').addClass('menutext');  
        menuText.filter('[linkId="'+offsets[div].id+'"]').addClass('menutext2').removeClass('menutext');
      }
    }
    if ( start === 0 ) { menuText.removeClass('menutext2').addClass('menutext'); }
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ijiwom/2/edit

EDIT :

http://jsbin.com/ijiwom/3/edit

EDIT 2 :

http://jsbin.com/ijiwom/4/edit

EDIT 3 :

http://jsbin.com/ijiwom/5/edit

Comment: I have only another one problem, when I get back to top the style have to get back to the first style and it doesn't why? how can I fix that?

Comment: I have another problem jsut fix it and everything is perfect. when I scroll to the second div I get through the first div of course, your code change the first menu ul style and the second ul style(because I scroll to both of the divs) but it should change only one of the menu ul's style depends on my position for example if I were on the first div the first ul style change from menutext to menutext2, when I scroll to the second div, the second ul style should change from menutext to menutext2 BUT the first ul style should change from menutext2 to menutext(as it was) could you do it please?

Comment: can you please answer my question in the last comment?

Comment: It's spectacular code you are genius, for now you fixed two problems with it that I had, but there's one last problem that I will be thankful to you if you fix it. When I scroll for example to the first div the first ul style change but when I return to top(to space without any divs) the first ul style still the same but it have to change to the first style as it was because I'm not on the first div, same thing if I scrolled to a place that no divs on it(for example in the end of the page there's no div so all uls have to be as it was)

Comment: Can you please answer my question? promise it's the last if it was fixed PLeaseee I really need it ://

Comment: Done, but this is not "write your code" website. Use a library for this, like the second answer provided!

Answer (score 1):

dringchev gave you a working example.

what you are describing is sometimes called a "scroll spy", for example here in bootstrap:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

you could also implement it using jquery waypoints

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17375/what-is-the-navigation-concept-bootstrap-uses-called for a discussion of this UX pattern

Comment: Yep, he should use something like this, since working with some library for this is what makes your code less buggy and cross-browser.